# I can't store users' answers in a simple .txt file?

Tags: php, forms, store

I am new to php so I was trying to make a simple multiple choice quiz app , one question at a time so when the user click the submit button it goes to the next question so the questions are in different php files , so I was trying to store the answers in a simple answers.txt file using the fopen , fwrite  functions , but the problem is that when I tried to answer the quiz questions myself .. it doesnt create the answers.txt file , so I created it manually but it remains empty and here is the first questions' php code :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['q1']) && !empty($_GET['q1'])) {
    $answer1 = $_GET['q1'];
    $heranswers = fopen("Nanswers.txt ", "a+");
    fwrite($heranswers, $answer1);
}
?>
```

so what's wrong with this ?

Comment: is your file atleast opening

Comment: nope , nothing happens at all , it's like the code doesnt exist .

Comment: it may look intermediating but a database is actually less work than manipulating txt files

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the if loop

```
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        die(error_get_last());
    }

    // Write $answer1 to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $answer1) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        die(error_get_last());
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($answer1) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
```

Atleast you will find the error

Answer (score 0):

make sure file permission .. it should be writable...

```
<?php

$answer1 = 10;
$filename = "Nanswers.txt";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.

if (is_writable($filename)) {

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a+')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        die(error_get_last());
    }

    // Write $answer1 to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $answer1) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        die(error_get_last());
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($answer1) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

Comment: also noticed you have a space in your file name "Nanswers.txt "  .. it should not have space "Nanswers.txt"